# Content showing in statusbar when scrolling in PWA

Tags: css, progressive-web-apps

Im currently developing my first PWA with Vue and NuxtJS. I want a custom color and have set the correct meta for adding the body background color of my page (same as the header, purple).

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

However, when i scroll the content it shows above the fixed header, in the statusbar due to the transparency... How can i solve this?

[image]

The result im looking for when scrolling is:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

its possible by setting the body to overflow hidden and an inner div to overflow auto... but better solution is here: https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

by setting:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max Di Campo. This solution worked for me. In my PWA, the body content was showing behind the status bar when body is scrolled. To hide the content, I used a `<div>` like this -

```html
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 100; left: 0; top: -80px; width: 100vw; height: 80px; background: #4411aa;"></div>
```